# Activity displays incorrect when launched on a secondary virtualdisplay

Tags: android, api, user-interface, display, android-virtualdisplay

In my scenario, I want to mirror another app in my app.

I use `DisplayManager` to `createVirtualDisplay` for my `SurfaceView`. Then I set `DisplayId` as this `VirtualDisplay` in `AcitivityOptions` when I start activity.

By this process, another app can be launched successfully in my surfaceview. But there are some display problems. According to my test, only image, background color and `GLSurfaceView.Renderer` are rendered correctly. The ui-component such as `TextView` and `Button` are not rendered in `SurfaceView`.

From the above test result, I guess it may be related to the depth or order of rendering.

The example code is as followed:

```
SurfaceView surfaceView = findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
int flags = DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_PRESENTATION |
        DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_PUBLIC |
        DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_AUTO_MIRROR;

DisplayManager displayManager = (DisplayManager) getSystemService(Context.DISPLAY_SERVICE);
VirtualDisplay virtualDisplay = displayManager.createVirtualDisplay("MyVirtualDisplay",
        surfaceView.getWidth(), surfaceView.getHeight(), 1, surfaceView.getHolder().getSurface(),
        flags);

int displayId = virtualDisplay.getDisplay().getDisplayId();
ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeBasic().setLaunchDisplayId(displayId);

Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(appName);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCH_ADJACENT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
```

By contrast, if I mirror same activity to a `Display` instead of `VirtualDisplay`, which can be captured by `MediaRouter` or `DisplayManager`. In this way, everything displays correctly (In my test, I simulate the second monitor by "Developer Options" -> "Simulate Secondary Displays"):

```
MediaRouter mediaRouter = (MediaRouter)getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_ROUTER_SERVICE);
MediaRouter.RouteInfo route = mediaRouter.getSelectedRoute(MediaRouter.ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO);
Display presentationDisplay = route.getPresentationDisplay();
int displayId = presentationDisplay.getDisplayId();

Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(appName);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCH_ADJACENT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeBasic().setLaunchDisplayId(displayId);

startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
```

Is there any process I miss or any flags I misconfigure in virtual display mode? Thanks for any help.

P.S. To mirror another app, I have rooted and launched as system app.

Comment: I have encountered a similar problem. No matter how I set it up, I can't start the application on the virtual display. Can you give me some sample code?

Comment: I second @forDream, is it possible to share a GitHub link for the code which is working. Am too getting security exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem was calling createVirtualDisplay with wrong densityDpi, it should be more large numbers, such as 480, 560.